# The Security Implications of Implementing Facebook Connect on your Website

Tags: security, wordpress

The organization I work for is rolling out a [Wordpress Multi-User](http://mu.wordpress.org/) install for it's members to have a "Personal Mini-Website/Blog," that will be hosted on our main organization's website.  They are looking at using a Wordpress plugin which would allow users to comment on the blogs via [Facebook Connect](http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php).

I wanted to hear your thoughts on what the risks of using Facebook Connect in this type of a scenario would be.  (Or any scenario, really)

From both a SysAdmin & a Dev viewpoint.

Comment: It means Facebook can impersonate any of your users, and if a flaw in their login process is ever discovered then it may be exploited by a malicious person to login as anyone they want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of Facebook connect is that it adds an option for Facebook users to login to your blog and make comments.  The API also lets you see your WP comments in Facebook (and I believe viceversa).  I don't think this would be a security issue unless you were planning in making some blogs restricted.

If your concern is more about the actual API and how secure it is, you might want to post this in [**StackOverflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/) (...as it would be more of a programmer type question)